# what is wrong with this mysql code

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

```
$db_user="root";
$db_host="localhost";
$db_password="root";
$db_name = "fayer";
$conn = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name) or die ("couldn't connect to server");

// perform query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM posts';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");

// use returned data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

I get in the browser: "mysql problem".

Help!

---

### UPDATE

I have echoed the query. It shows `SELECT * FROM posts` and when I query manually it gets the rows.

I think it has something to do with mysqli. I think i should use mysql. Do u think I have incompatibility problems with mysqli?

---

i have echoed it. it shows SELECT * FROM posts. and when i query manually it gets the rows.

i think it has something to do with mysqli. i think i should use mysql. do u think i have incompatibility problems with mysqli?

Comment: are you going to change the question so that answers become invalid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have empty WHERE clause. Remove it or add a search condition.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute query because: " . mysqli_error());
```

and you will know why the query is failing. Rule of thumb: Whenever you have a failed query, print it out and run it through phpmyadmin or some other raw-query executor and you will discover very quickly what the problem is.

Comment: i forgot to delete it. here is my new code and i still have problem!